# Why is fscanf failing while reading characters?

Tags: c++, scanf

I have the following sample data file titled "data.txt":

```
a<tab>b<tab>c<newline>
a<tab>b<tab>c<newline>
```

and the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char a,b,c;
  FILE* fin = fopen("data.txt","r");

  fscanf(fin,"%c %c %c",&a,&b,&c);
  cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<endl;

  fscanf(fin,"%c %c %c",&a,&b,&c);
  cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<endl;

  fclose(fin);

  return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run, its output is as follows:

```
a b c
     a b
```

I expected to see:

```
a b c
a b c
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not skipping whitespace between the third and fourth character read - you need another space in one of the format strings.

(Why `fscanf` in C++ though?)

Comment: Makes sense and works! Thanks!
Isn't fstream much slower than fscanf, since it involves a wrapper around the basic fscanf implementation of C?

Comment: Not necessarily. And conciseness and type safety sometimes matter more.